# mouse hover tooltip hides inside the container

Tags: jquery, html, css, d3.js, rickshaw

I am using d3 and rickshaw.js. I have created a graph which is exactly [like](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html). The thing is that I have wrapped the complete graph inside a container of width 450px and height of 400px. And I have also added the hover effect on it.
Now the issue which I am facing is whenever I hover the mouse on the last graph co-ordinate the hover tool tip gets hidden inside the container and it is not visible or partially visible. I have even used z-index in my CSS. but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to make it work this way would be to append the tooltip to an element external to the container, e.g. make it a floating `div`.